# Steps to run MatLAB Slam with $GPRMC INS Data + Hesai Lidar scans

Tags: matlab, gps, pcap, slam, inertial-navigation

I hope you are all well. I was wondering, if I had $GPRMC INS Data and Hesai Lidar data, is there a way to use it in MATLAB together to run 3d slam? I tried looking through the documentation but I was a bit lost since the example that they used with the INS had different data fields than the  one I currently have. For reference, here is the $GPRMC format documentation:

https://docs.novatel.com/OEM7/Content/Logs/GPRMC.htm

Thank you!

I have loaded my pcap data from the Hesai Pandar32XT into Matlab using the "hesaiFileReader" in matlab. Following this, I have put every single pointcloud extracted into a matrix of its own

And alongside that, I have my INS log files in the $GPRMC format. Therefore, I was wondering, how can I combine these two pieces of information and then run the SLAM algorithim using them in MatLAB? Is there a library to interpret INS data in MatLAB and run SLAM with the provided pointclouds? Thank you once again.